# Limit relation to be referenced only once

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I have a SQL Server database with a schema that is roughly as follows:

Identifier:

| identifier_id | identifier | identifierString |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1234 | ABC1234 |
| 1 | 879 | ABC0879 |

The `identifier` and the `identifierString` are both set by the C# program and are used as an identifier for later use. This table can't be replaced by a sequence!

Lecturers and contractors may need an extra identifier in my code, then the identifier can't be used double, so if a lecturer has 879 as an identifier then no lecturer can have that and also not contractor, that is why I store it in a Table.

Contractors:

| contractor_is | identifier |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |

Lecturers:

| lecturer_id | identifier |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |

An entry from the identifier Table is used either by the contractors table or the lecturers table, an entry in these tables also can have null as identifier if it is not needed there.

I created the Database with DataGrip and used the `Scaffold-DbContext` command from Visual Studio to create the Ef Core Model.

The foreign key is on the side of the contractor/lecturer side.

But in the model it creates lists on the identifier model, meaning that one Identifier could be used for multiple  contractors and/or lecturers.

Is there a way to define the tables so that identifier can only be referenced once?

A quick search showed me that I can't create one column from identifier to the other two tables so that they reference each other.

Comment: Scaffolding can only scaffold what it sees. It can't guess that you intend to use `Identifier` as something other than an entity. There are no either-or FK constraints. What is the purpose of that table in the first place? Should it be replaced by `SEQUENCE` perhaps?

Comment: A better way to model an identifier shared by multiple entities is to create a SEQUENCE in the database and use `NEXT VALUE FOR ThatSequence` as the default value of the ID field. Not just as an extra key, but the key itself. To ORMs like EF Core this will appear the same as any database-generated value. In MySQL and other databases that have no SEQUENCE types you can emulate them with triggers

Comment: the identifier is not a number of a sequence and thus can't be replaced by a sequence. This is a simplified example of my database.

Comment: Post an actual example in that case, including actual table definitions and explaining what you really want. Scaffolding can't guess your intentions, it can only work with what's in the database. The database says that the same identifier can be used in multiple tables. If you want unique `identifier` *per table* you'll have to add a Unique CHECK or index in every table.

Comment: Do you want to navigate from Identifier to Contractors or Lecturers? In that case you need the collections. If not, just remove them. This won't affect the database or how the queries work

Comment: I want the database restricted so that it can't add an identifier that is already used in the contractors table into the lecturers table. Currently if I add an Identifier in my code and add it to a lecturer the database would allow me to also add it to an contracor, but I do not want that. Your mentioning of the index is a good idea, but to my knowledge it only works to assure that one identifier is only used once in that table, but not used in other tables.

Comment: Also I do not want to navigate from Identifier to lecturers or contractors, it is intended to only be created and requested from them and an identifier can't be double between the two of them, hence the table.

Comment: Post a real example, not a simplification. There's no way to do what you want in the database short of using a trigger in both tables to ensure there's no value in the other table. If instead of `identifier` you had a `Person` from which `Contractor` and `Lecturer` inherited though, the application ensure uniqueness up to a point, because the same `Person` can't be a `Contractor` and `Lecturer` at the same time. Unless they can, which is actually possible if a lecturer can also do extra work as a contractor.

Comment: One way to specify the constraint in the database would be to use an intermediate table From `Identifier/Person` to the other two, with FKs going through that table instead of directly from `Identifier` to `Lecturer`. A UNIQUE index on `identifier` would ensure only one relation record would be allowed at a time. That would result in an uglier model though, or require mapping to a view. I'm not sure this would be worth it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your answer with the junction table is as you said probably not the finest solution, but it is exactly what I need in this case. After some consideration the solution could be made with a combination of your comments using 2 references from the identifier to the other tables and a check to ensure that either one of these references is null. Scaffold as you said just scaffolds what it sees and that will probably then make the model even more chaotic, but that seems to be necessary to make it work right. Thank you for your help now I found the answer.